# Renamed foreign key associations in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This project uses sqlite and sequelize. I'm used to normal sql, but this method looks useful for creating an API in Node.js.

I have two models: user and group. A group has many users, but one is a teacher. I have a separate UserInGroup table to handle the many-to-many, but for the teacher one-to-many relation, I have renamed the relation 'teacher' (and so the attribute is teacherId).

```
db.group.belongsTo(db.user, {as: 'teacher'});   
db.user.hasMany(db.group, {as: 'teacher'});
```

When I log in and try to create the group object, it tries to make a userId field, which obviously doesn't exist. How can I make it put the userId in the teacherId field?

```
app.post('/groups', middleware.requireAuthentication, function(request, response){

    var body = _.pick(request.body, 'name', 'description');
    body.description = body.description.trim();
    body.name = body.name.trim();

    db.group.create(body).then(function(group){              
        request.user.addGroup(group).then(function(){
            return group.reload();
        }).then(function(group){
            response.json(group.toJSON())   
        })
    }, function (e) {                                   
        response.status(400).json(e);
    })
});
```

I don't want to simply rename the field, because I will also be managing a "message" object that needs to take two userIds for sender and recipient. I've defined all the fields in db.js, but I'm not sure how to fill them.

Answer (score 2):

```
db.group.belongsTo(db.user, {as: 'teacher',foreignKey: 'teacherId'});   
db.user.hasMany(db.group, {as: 'teacher',foreignKey: 'teacherId'});
```

Ref : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/

Answer (score 0):

In my case `Businesscategory` has relatiship with `BusinessProduct` model
table.

The actual table name is

`Businesscategory` = `businesscategories`
And
`BusinessProduct` = `business_products`

now for relationship  `BusinessProduct.businesscategory_id` should be there inside `BusinessProduct` table but i change that field with `product_category_id`

so now following  error i was facing

```
Unknown column 'BusinessProducts.businesscategory_id' in 'on clause'
```

so i use following code to solve this issue.
its works for me.

```
 module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Businesscategory = sequelize.define('Businesscategory', {
    category_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    category_icon: DataTypes.STRING,
    is_delete: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, { underscored: true });
  Businesscategory.associate = function (models) {
    Businesscategory.hasMany(models.BusinessProduct,
      {
        foreignKey: 'product_category_id'
      },
      {
        onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
        onUpdate: 'RESTRICT'
      });


  };
  return Businesscategory;
};
```